# Merge background image using CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a background image for `div`.
Same image is used for responsive.

[image]

Here is the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/geisD)

What I want is image should not be seen as if cut off for responsive.

I want CSS to image merged in color.

- I have last option to add already merged image as a background.
- Would like to have CSS solution for merging the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done adjusting `box-shadow: inset`  for each resolution using media query.

Here is [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hvlbt) for it.